# How to inject WSClient in a Play framework project when using Maven?

Tags: scala, maven, playframework, ws-client

When creating a Play framework project and using `WSClient` to make REST call, the official Play framework documentation suggests to add `ws` to the `build.sbt` to manage dependencies. If using Maven the ws dependency is included in:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.typesafe.play</groupId>
  <artifactId>play-ws_2.12</artifactId>
  <version>${play2.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

However when trying to make a call to a web service using a snipped like this:

```scala
@Singleton
class Controller @Inject()(
  ws: WSClient,
  controllerComponents: ControllerComponents
)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext)
  extends AbstractController(controllerComponents) {
  def callApi(): Action[AnyContent] = Action.async { _ =>
    ws
      .url("https://mywebservice.com/api/bla")
      .get()
      .map(response => Ok(response.body.toString))
  }
}
```

Then the following error appears:

```
CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) No implementation for play.api.libs.ws.WSClient was bound.
  while locating play.api.libs.ws.WSClient
    for the 1st parameter of controllers.MyController.<init>(MyController.scala:13)
  while locating controllers.MyController
    for the 3rd parameter of router.Routes.<init>(Routes.scala:33)
  at play.api.inject.RoutesProvider$.bindingsFromConfiguration(BuiltinModule.scala:123):
Binding(class router.Routes to self) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$4)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the documentation says:

> Note: In Play 2.6, Play WS has been split into two, with an underlying
>   standalone client that does not depend on Play, and a wrapper on top
>   that uses Play specific classes. In addition, shaded versions of
>   AsyncHttpClient and Netty are now used in Play WS to minimize library
>   conflicts, primarily so that Play’s HTTP engine can use a different
>   version of Netty. Please see the 2.6 migration guide for more
>   information.

Looking at the 2.6 migration guide we can read:

> If you have a Play SBT project, you can still add WS by adding the
>   following line to your build.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies += ws
```

> **This includes the play-ahc-ws module [...]**

So to resolve the issue we have to add the **play-ahc-ws** module to the Maven's pom.xml:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.typesafe.play</groupId>
  <artifactId>play-ahc-ws_2.12</artifactId>
  <version>${play2.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

If using Guice like in the code sample, the dependency injection will be handled by Guice.